# MySQL BETWEEN without endpoints

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL's BETWEEN includes all results between two endpoints **as well as the endpoints**.

> If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal
>   to max, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it returns 0. This is equivalent
>   to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max) if all the arguments
>   are of the same type. REFERENCE- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Is there an function like `REALLYBETWEEN` which doesn't include the endpoints, or am I stuck using `min < expr AND expr < max`?

Comment: You're stuck... And that's not such a bad thing. it is at least explicit.

Comment: `BETWEEN min + 1 AND max - 1`, if you're working with integral type.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski.  Thanks.  Been searching and didn't find anything but wasn't certain.  Good news was before today, I thought BETWEEN didn't include the endpoints.  At least now I know.

Comment: @mellamokb Wow, that's superbly hard to parse in my brain.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I know, right :) It was a tongue-in-cheek answer.

Comment: @mellamokb.  I think this will be a performance hit as it will eliminate the use of indexes.  No?

Comment: @user1032531 . . .Actually, this may be a good question.  I think all alternatives may result in the left hand side being evaluated twice, whereas with the between it would only be evaluated once.  If the comparison is for an expensive function or a subquery, this could have significant performance implications.

Comment: @GordonLinoff.  If the comparison is expensive, to you have a recommended approach? - NEVER MIND, JUST READ YOUR EDIT POST.  THANKS!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you can just write it yourself as:

```
where val > start and val < end
```

Between is:

```
where val >= start and val <= end
```

As for indexes, the first two should use an index correctly and identically to `between`, assuming that start and end are constants.  I'm not sure if the last version will.

If val is a complicated expression, then consider the following:

```
select *
from (your query here) t
where t.val > start and t.val < end
```

This should evaluate `val` only once.  I think the other forms would evaluate it twice.

Or, you could do:

```
where val between start and end and val not in (start, end)
```

Comment: Your last suggestion is a creative way how to use BETWEEEN without endpoints!  Don't think anyone should use it, but it definitely answered the question.  I will continue using the first two solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `BETWEEN` is an expression, not a function.  It's just a coding convenience and means exactly what is says.  There is no performance benefit.

To exclude the endpoints, you must code it yourself.

Comment: I wonder if this is really true.  There may be some databases where the left side (`val`) is evaluated only once for `between` but would be evaluated twice for two comparisons.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I can't say it is universal, but on the databases I use, running an EXPLAIN reveals that `a between x and y` is executed as `a >= x and a <= y`.